# what is the zsh equivalent of bash's export -f

Tags: shell-script, zsh, function

So I started using `zsh`. I like it all right. It seems very cool and slick, and the fact that the current working directory and actual command line are on different lines is nice, but at the same time, I'm noticing that `zsh` can be a bit slower than `bash`, especially when printing text to the screen.

The thing I liked best was the fact that `zsh` was 'backward compatible' with all of the functions I defined in my `.bashrc`.

One gripe though. The functions all work perfectly, but I can't figure out how the exporting system works.

I had some of those `.bashrc` functions exported so that I could use them elsewhere, such as in scripts and external programs, with `export -f`.

In zsh, exporting doesn't seem to even be talked about. Is it autoloading? Are those two things the same? I'm having a seriously hard time figuring that out.

Comment: This is a very old question, but I want to say that "the current working directory and actual command line are on different lines" has nothing at all to do with zsh. It depends on how you set up your prompt, that's all.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Environment variables containing functions are a bash hack. Zsh doesn't have anything similar. You can do something similar with a few lines of code. Environment variables contain strings; older versions of bash, before [Shellshock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellshock_(software_bug)) was discovered, stored the function's code in a variable whose name is that of the function and whose value is `() {` followed by the function's code followed by `}`. You can use the following code to import variables with this encoding, and attempt to run them with bash-like settings. Note that zsh cannot emulate all bash features, all you can do is get a bit closer (e.g. to make `$foo` split the value and expand wildcards, and make arrays 0-based).

```
bash_function_preamble='
    emulate -LR ksh
'
for name in ${(k)parameters}; do
  [[ "-$parameters[name]-" = *-export-* ]] || continue
  [[ ${(P)name} = '() {'*'}' ]] || continue
  ((! $+builtins[$name])) || continue
  functions[$name]=$bash_function_preamble${${${(P)name}#"() {"}%"}"}
done
```

(As [Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%c3%a9phane-chazelas), the original discoverer of Shellshock, noted, an earlier version of this answer could execute arbitrary code at this point if the function definition was malformed. This version doesn't, but of course as soon as you execute any command, it could be a function imported from the environment.)

Post-Shellshock versions of bash encode functions in the environment using invalid variable names (e.g. `BASH_FUNC_myfunc%%`). This makes them harder to parse reliably as zsh doesn't provide an interface to extract such variable names from the environment.

I don't recommend doing this. Relying on exported functions in scripts is a bad idea: it creates an invisible dependency in your script. If you ever run your script in an environment that doesn't have your function (on another machine, in a cron job, after changing your shell initialization files, …), your script won't work anymore. Instead, store all your functions in one or more separate files (something like `~/lib/shell/foo.sh`) and start your scripts by importing the functions that it uses (`. ~/lib/shell/foo.sh`). This way, if you modify `foo.sh`, you can easily search which scripts are relying on it. If you copy a script, you can easily find out which auxiliary files it needs.

Zsh (and ksh before it) makes this more convenient by providing a way to automatically load functions in scripts where they are used. The constraint is that you can only put one function per file. Declare the function as autoloaded, and put the function definition in a file whose name is the name of the function. Put this file in a directory listed in `$fpath` (which you may configure through the `FPATH` environment variable). In your script, declare autoloaded functions with `autoload -U foo`.

Furthermore zsh can compile scripts, to save parsing time. Call [`zcompile`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-compilation) to compile a script. This creates a file with the `.zwc` extension. If this file is present then `autoload` will load the compiled file instead of the source code. You can use the [`zrecompile` function](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#Recompiling-Functions) to (re)compile all the function definitions in a directory.

Comment: Funny how your code has the same shellshock vulnerability `bash` had (doesn't verify that the content of the variable is _only_ a function definition and processes any variable name like `HTTP_HOST` or `LC_X`). Good answer otherwise.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas If you're going to run commands with functions imported from the environment, you've pretty much lost. But I've updated the import code to not execute arbitrary code. It isn't very useful though, since post-shellshock bash doesn't encode its exported functions in the same way.

Comment: You've now fixed the equivalent of CVE-2014-6271, but are still probably exposed to many vulnerabilities of the type of  CVE-2014-6277/6278... as you're still exposing the zsh parser to code in any variable including some that are potentially under control of attackers in some contexts (as the code in `zsh -c 'functions[f]=$VAR'`  is _parsed_ even if the `f` function is never called). The solution is to consider only variables whose name follow a reserved template like those `$BASH_FUNC_x%%`, but as you say, `zsh` has  no API to list or retrieve those. You'd need to call `perl` for instance.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1515680/export-f-equivalent-in-zsh/1515756#1515756

Answer (score 15):

If you put your function declaration in **.zshenv**, your function will be usable from a script without any effort.

Comment: Why did you downvote my answer? Please explain.

Comment: Still waiting for an answer and still working!

Comment: I just discovered this answer and it is an ideal solution.

Comment: I didn't downvote it. And TBH the OP was asking about exporting stuff from .bashrc, which is kind of a bad idea, better to put it in a script so you don't end up with a huge environment. But your solution is just a variant of that same bad idea, put all your scripts in `.zshenv` and it slows down every invocation of zsh by parsing a lot of code that never gets used. Further it is not the same as exporting a function, just like an exported variable, an exported function is only available to child processes. Whereas the stuff you put in `.zshenv` is available to every zsh.

Comment: Finally if you rely on personal code you put in your `.zshenv`, then all your scripts will be totally non-portable. Normally scripts could depend on each other, which is fine, you distribute them together. But if they depend on having special functions in `.zshenv`, no one will want to use them, or they would have to be invoked with a special `ZDOTDIR`, preventing your own `.zshenv` from being executed. It would be a pain.

Answer (score 1):

Everywhere I've read about this suggests that automatically importing functions is a bad idea, so I decided to just extract my scripts into a separate file that can be easily sourced in a subshell.

I called the shared file `.zshared`.

```bsh
# ~/.zshared
function say-hello() {
  echo "Hello, $1\!"
}
```

I sourced it in my `.zshrc`.

```bsh
# ~/.zshrc
source ~/.zshared
```

In any scripts that need access to those functions, I just source `.zshared`.

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
source ~/.zshared

say-hello "David" # Hello, David!
```

It requires a little work initially to get your scripts updated, but you still get to define your functions in one place without much overhead.