# How to get functions propagated to subshell?

Tags: shell, function, subshell, env

Solaris / sh

I have a few functions defined in a file which gets loaded via

```
. ./some_file.sh
```

When I start a subshell with

```
sh
```

All my function definitions are lost but when I do

```
env
```

I do see the source, is there an easy way to get them functional in my subshell?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Functions are naturally propagated to *subshells*:

```
greet () {
  echo "hello, $1"
}
( echo "this is a subshell"; greet bob )
```

But they are not and cannot be propagated to independent shell processes that you start by invoking the shell under its name.

[Bash has an extension to pass functions through the environment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59360/what-is-the-zsh-equivalent-of-bashs-export-f), but there's no such thing in other shells. While you can emulate the feature, it requires running code in the nested shell anyway. You might as well source your function definitions in the nested shell.

Answer (score 15):

You can propagate functions *from bash to bash* subshells:

```
function greet1 {
  echo "moin, $1"
}
typeset -fx greet1

greet2() {
  echo "servus, $1"
}
typeset -fx greet2

echo "greet1 bob; greet2 alice" | bash
```

Output:

```
moin, bob
servus, alice
```

Also, see https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/upt/ch29_13.htm

Comment: We prefer our answers to have a bit more explanation.   And, if you’re going to link to another site, at least tell us what’s there.

Comment: Wow! This is first time when I saw answer by some "anon" user much better than top 0.01.

Comment: `typeset` is a synonym for `declare`. For full usage details, type `help declare` at a Bash prompt.