# Make 'entr' execute a locally defined shell function

Tags: linux, shell-script

`entr` is used to run shell commands when files change. The following script will output *File changed.* whenever the file */tmp/data.txt* is modified.

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

echo "/tmp/data.txt" | entr -s 'echo "File changed."'
```

Once the commands to execute become more complex it would be convenient to move them to a separate function and make `entr` call the function, like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

foo() { echo "File changed!"; }

echo "$0" | entr -s 'foo' # Error: command not found: foo
```

Unfortunately, this raises a **command not found** error, which suggests that my locally defined function is not available to `entr`. Is there a way to make this work and what's the underlying problem here?

Kind regards

Comment: `bash` allows you to `export` the function.  Any reason apart from neatness that stops you executing a script rather than a function?

Comment: To clarify the above, variables (and presumably functions) from a script are not normally defined in the environment of the commands they call.  To get a variable or function to persist across the call to the command you need to tag them as inheritable with the export command/keyword.

Comment: @icarus Executing a script would require passing many parameters to that script which makes everything less intelligible. Neatness all the way!

Comment: @davolfman I have attempted to do so using bash's `export -f` which did not change anything.

Comment: @Slavistan make sure that $SHELL inside the script is bash and not sh. However I  expect that if your aim is not to pass lots of parameters either via the command line or the environment then you will be disappointed. Can I introduce you to the concept of a script which writes a script which it then executes?

Comment: You had a syntax error in your examples. Please set `export SHELL=/bin/bash` before the `entr` command and try again your last example.

Comment: What is `entr`? It's not a standard Unix utility as far as I know, and it's not a utility I've seen used before.

Comment: @Kusalananda `entr` is not a standard Unix utility but is available from the package managers of many linux distributions. See http://eradman.com/entrproject/ for a overview. You'll know within three minutes whether that's a useful utility to you or not.

Comment: @mosvy That did the trick indeed. Would you care to create a proper answer? Thank you.

Comment: Please put your conclusions in a separate "self-"answer, so it could be appraised separately from the question. In this case, your assertion that exporting variables "gets messy very quickly" is quite dubious, as all bourne shells support `set -a` (long way `set -o allexport`) since like forever.

Answer (score 0):

You should `export SHELL=/bin/bash` before invoking `env -s cmd` if you want to be able to use bash exported functions inside `cmd`.

As documented in the [manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/unstable/entr/entr.1.en.html) of `entr` (emphasis mine):

> `-s`
>       Evaluate the first argument using the interpreter **specified by the `SHELL` environment variable**.

Not necessarily `/bin/bash`, the shell it was called from, or the login shell of the user.

If `SHELL` is not defined (it doesn't have to, in a script, etc), then `entr` will set it itself to `/bin/sh`, which on Debian is `dash`, a shell which cannot use the functions exported by `bash` and, moreover, will [*remove*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/498952/308316) them from the environment.

Comment: This works for self-contained functions but fails if variables defined in the script need to be accesses. I've updated the question.

Comment: You should export the variables too: `export x`. How could they work otherwise? The shell doesn't support any kind of closures, especially NOT through exported functions ;-)

Comment: If you wonder how exporting functions work in bash, it's by creating some environment variables which contain the _source code_ of the function, which will be _parsed_ by the inner bash. Thence ShellShock and all the fun.

Comment: @Slavistan: I think I already know your next __Q:__ Why does `export x=1; echo "$0" | entr -s 'x=2; echo set x to 2'; echo "$x"` NOT set `x` to `2`? __A:__ because Unix is not plan9, LOL ;-)

Comment: That would make a good interview question :p Thanks for the lead! If I got everything right my problem is caused by the fact that [functions are propagated to subshells but they cannot be propagated to independent shell processes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65751/how-to-get-functions-propagated-to-subshell) which is what `entr -s` is doing. I'll probably generate a script and execute that with entr =) Oh, and .. plan9? I will have to get to know that at some point in time. [cat-v.org](http://www.cat-v.org) had me curious already!