# Process `zsh` function with util that only recognizes commands

Tags: zsh

(This question uses the Mac `caffeinate` tool as an example, but the concept applies to all tools (i.e. `xargs`) that accept a utility as argument.)

Mac's `caffeinate` tool accepts the name of a utility: `caffeinate sleep 1`, for instance, (where `sleep` is the utility).  Is there any way for it to accept a `zsh` function as well, without modifying the tool itself?  For example:

```
function mysleep {
  sleep 2
}

caffeinate mysleep    # mysleep: No such file or directory
```

Edit: This question is indeed a duplicate for Bash—thanks for pointing me to the answer.  For zsh, however, `export -f` doesn't work.  Is there a way to do this in zsh?  (I'm removing the `bash` tag to reduce confusion.)

Comment: @agc, [How to use defined function with xargs](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/158564) was for `bash` which has function export support. Here, it's for `zsh`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, The Q is tagged `/bash`, (and `/zsh`), so the boundaries seem a bit fuzzy.

Comment: @agc @ StéphaneChazelas Yes, I'm looking for a zsh answer now.

Comment: (I assumed bash and zsh would behave similarly when I first wrote the answer.  Apologies for the confusion.)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, thanks for the correction.  Alas, now this Q needs to be **un**duplicated.

Comment: Related question: [what is the zsh equivalent of bash's export -f](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59360/what-is-the-zsh-equivalent-of-bashs-export-f).

Comment: Related methods:  1) for *GNU* `parallel` borrowed from [*Tange*'s 5/17/15 post on *unix.com*](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/257889-parallel-processing-functions-xargs.html):  `foo() { echo "$1$1$1$1$1$1" ; } ; export fun="$(typeset -f foo)"; parallel 'eval "$fun";'foo ::: baz` outputs `bazbazbazbazbazbaz`, also 2) using `xargs`, adapted from *jawsnnn*'s post from the same URL: `seq 10 | xargs -I% --max-procs=5 zsh -c "$(typeset -f foo)"';foo "%"'`

Answer (score 1):

[`caffeinate`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/caffeinate.8.html) expects to execute a command in a new process.

To interpret a `zsh` function, you need a `zsh` command.

And you'd need to pass the definition of that function (as well as other functions it may need) to it, for instance with:

```
mysleep() {
  sleep 2
}
caffeinate zsh -c "$(functions mysleep);mysleep"
```

`functions mysleep` dumps the definition of the `mysleep` function which we pass to that new `zsh` for interpretation before calling the function, so that `zsh` invoked by `caffeinate` ends up interpreting:

```
mysleep() {
  sleep 2
};mysleep
```

If we compare to `bash`'s:

```
mysleep() {
  sleep 2
}
export -f mysleep
caffeinate bash -c "mysleep"
```

(which is 2 characters shorter to type), `bash` will do:

```
execve("/path/to/caffeinate",
  ["caffeinate", "bash", "-c", "mysleep"],
  ["BASH_FUNC_mysleep%%=() {  sleep 2\n}", rest-of-environment])
```

While with `zsh`, we get:

```
execve("/path/to/caffeinate",
  ["caffeinate", "zsh", "-c", "mysleep () {\n\tsleep 2\n};mysleep"],
  [rest-of-environment])
```

I see several advantages of that latter approach:

- we have full control: we know how we pass the function definition, how it is being used. There's less scope for nasty things like the type of shellshock here.
- as the name of the bash environment variable that carries the function definition contains `%` characters (and even if it didn't, think of `sudo` for instance), we're not guaranteed guaranteed that `caffeinate` will propagate it to the `bash` command it runs.
- if it is propagate, because the function definition is stored in envp[] instead of argv[], that means it pollutes the environment of every other command executed in that environment (including `sleep` for instance in this example).
- (minor) even though the `bash` shell code is shorter, that's more data passed to `execve()` so contributes more toward the E2BIG limit of that system call.

If you wanted to use the environment, you could still do:

```
FUNCS=$(functions mysleep) caffeinate zsh -c '
  eval "$FUNCS";mysleep'
```

In the case of `caffeinate` here, that is where we only need for `caffeinate` to run while the function is running, not necessarily for it to run the function, we can use other approaches like:

```
mysleep | caffeinate cat
```

`cat` will run as long as `mysleep` runs. `mysleep` would still run in a separate process and that affects the stdout of `mysleep` though.

```
mysleep 3> {fd}>(caffeinate cat)
```

would solve both problems.

As above, that creates a pipe between `mysleep` and `cat`. But the writing end of the pipe is now on a newly allocate file descriptor above 10 (stored in `$fd`) that `mysleep` will typically not write to. `cat` will therefore read nothing but wait until end-of-file on the pipe which will only happen when `mysleep` (and all the children processes that inherit that fd)  terminates.

Comment: `caffeinate zsh -c "$(functions mysleep); mysleep"` is an interesting solution.  It works, which is a big plus.  However, if the function definition is multilined, this could get messy real quick.  Ideally I'd like to define the function outside the `caffeinate` call (and also not in a file as suggested in another answer).  For bash, the answer to all of these requirements is `export -f func`, but I don't know of a zsh equivalent.

Comment: @DanielLi, there's no problem with multilines here. The main difference between `bash`'s "export -f" is that the function definition is passed in argv[] (in that argument to "-c") instead of envp[] (in a `BASH_FUNC_mysleep%%` variable now after shellshock). See edit that may clarify in case you misinterpreted the answer in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is simply put your function in a script file and call the script as such:

```
caffeinate myfunction.sh
```

Contents of myfunction.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 2
```

make sure the script file is executable or it will give you a permission error:

```
chmod +x myfunction.sh
```

Comment: Good suggestion, but for my use case, I'm looking for a non-file-based approach.