# export -f function results in invalid options in zsh

Tags: bash, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I want to make my aliases available to sub-shells like this in my `~/.zshrc`

```bash
say_hello() {
  echo "Hello!"
}

export -f say_hello
```

However when I'm sourcing my `~/.zshrc` I get this error:

`~/.zshrc:export:159: invalid option(s)`

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/59431/432774.

Comment: Thanks, this answer from the referred post solved it for me: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/406781/133942